# (SOLVED) Shopify/Facebook unused JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, shopify

When running page speed analytics on my site, I've noticed that under the 'Reduce Unused JavaScript' suggestions, that there is a facebook JS running:

https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/161805988603854?v=2.9.111&r=stable

By far the worse JS that is affecting my website. But I cannot find anywhere to remove that from my Shopify theme.

I haven't installed any Facebook apps or entered any Facebook pixel coding manually.

Can someone please help me identify where this is and how to remove it, as my store speed is awful at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure those `https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/...` URLs _have_ something to do with a Facebook pixel though. If you did not specify any pixel ID, then shopify is probably using their own "default" one ...? Install the pixel helper Chrome extension, then you can check if there is any pixels embedded in the page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/meta-pixel/support/pixel-helper/

Comment: Thanks. Before I had chance to try your suggestion, I actually found an old Gtag that was pulling that through - so all gone now! 